# How to set active group-item after link redirect?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set an active group-item on another page when the user gets redirected. How can I do this? There are two states for the second page. I want the 2nd group tab only active when the user gets redirected via my jQuery function below.

HTML:

```
div class="card overflow-hidden">
                <div class="row no-gutters row-bordered row-border-light">
                    <div class="col-md-3 pt-0">
                        <div class="list-group list-group-flush group-settings-links">
                            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active in" id="tabonetoggle" data-toggle="list" href="#tabone">Group tab 1</a>
                            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="tabtwotoggle" data-toggle="list" href="#tabtwo">Group tab 2</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JQuery:

```
      $('#first-group-tab').removeClass('active');
      $('#second-group-tab').addClass('active');
      window.location.href = base_url + "testurl.html";
```

Right now when I type `testurl.html#second-group-tab` or `testurl.html#tabtwo` in the url bar it doesnt even show the second tab as active, only when I manually click onthe tab it shows as active

Comment: Plz validate my answer if you find it usefull. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to IDS. IDS must be unique!

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp

I changed your ids names "***tabonetoggle***" by ***first-group-tab*** and ***second-group-tab***.

---

In your first html file, you need to set link with hash of your second tab

```js
$("#second-group-tab").click(function() {
  window.location.href = base_url + "testurl.html#second-group-tab";
});
```

```css
.active { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card overflow-hidden">
  <div class="row no-gutters row-bordered row-border-light">
      <div class="col-md-3 pt-0">
          <div class="list-group list-group-flush group-settings-links">
              <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active in" id="first-group-tab" data-toggle="list" href="#tabone">Group tab 1</a>
              <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="second-group-tab" data-toggle="list" href="#tabtwo">Group tab 2</a>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And in the second file "***testurl.html***", get the hash then select the right tab with class name "active".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash

```js
$(function() {
  // we get hash value 
  var hashValue = location.hash;
  
  hashValue = "#second-group-tab"; // this line is for test only
  
  // we check if the hash value is egal to your second tab name
  if (hashValue == "#second-group-tab") { 
    $(".list-group-item").removeClass("active");
    $(hashValue).addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.active { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card overflow-hidden">
  <div class="row no-gutters row-bordered row-border-light">
      <div class="col-md-3 pt-0">
          <div class="list-group list-group-flush group-settings-links">
              <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active in" id="first-group-tab" data-toggle="list" href="#tabone">Group tab 1</a>
              <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="second-group-tab" data-toggle="list" href="#tabtwo">Group tab 2</a>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Remove this line before testing on your side : `hashValue = "#second-group-tab"; // this line is for test only`